# Are resource demanding process divided into multiple processes?

Tags: python, linux, process, google-compute-engine

It is spotted on google cloud engine. Multiple instances of my script are created (by bash?). The reason might be that the script demands very high amount of memory. How is this division done exactly? Any performance impact?

[image]

**[UPDATE]** My mistake. These instances are threads created by python.

Comment: It looks like `python`, not `bash`...

Comment: @Poshi, The parent of all the python processes is bash, according to the parent ID.

Comment: @Poshi, you are right, these are threads created by python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overestimate the skills of the Python. Python is incapable to do even a multi-threaded process model, automatically dividing tasks into parallel executable sub-tasks is far over its limits.

This process is divided into sub-processes because it was written on this way.

The feature what you are estimating - automatically parallelize processes - is practically unsolvable in the general case, although it is still a hot Computer Science research topic.

Comment: The parent of all the python processes is bash, according to the parent ID. So I suspect it is not the python script that creates all the processes, but the bash somehow..

Comment: @user7586189 Doing that is practically impossible with the Linux API, because the processes can fork only their own children. The only way would be if bash would somehow "ask" the python to fork child processes by the tracing/debugging API, there isn't even any similar in the bash for that. Furthermore, the bash doesn't know anything from the internals of the python, parallelizing it would be a *deep* and *nearly impossible* task, requiring very deep restructuring of its internals. Believe, there is no such thing, the python makes its child processes because it is a single-threaded language.

Comment: @user7586189 Btw, the strength of the linux (on this basic level) is *not* that it would be so intelligent, its strength is that it does exactly what you say him.

Comment: I think you are right. Actually the number of threads (NLWP) matches the processes created. It is confusing that all these instances have their PID but are actually threads?

Comment: @user7586189 No, they are processes. In the Python world there is a custom that they call processes threads, but doing this, they are saying some different what their product is really doing. A thread means that they multiple execution control is running in the same address space. **No python process can do that, the python interpreter itself is totally incapable to do that, which is a simple single-threaded interpreter and it is nowhere from any multithreading process model. It is not even planned.** Furthermore, also your pstree clearly shows that these are processes, threads are enclosed in

Comment: @user7586189 `{}`, processes are in `[]`.  Check your firefox in a `pstree`, you will see difference! (In recent firefox, you have to see a parent process with some child-processes, and inside all child processes, you should see some threads). Python has its advantages and disadvantages, everybody may have their opinion how are they weighting them, but I am sure, that only few say for this that it would be an advantage of the Python.

Comment: @user7586189 Despite that, in some python docs you may find that they are talking about "threads", don't believe it. If they will be threads, then you will see it so in the `pstree` output, but in the foreseeable future you won't see that in any python software.